# HTML Issue with tables and anchor tags

Tags: html, html-table, href, anchor

Absolute beginner here. In lines 52-80 I created a table within a table to allow the star emojis to be placed next to the text (html, css, etc.) but for some reason after the table was made my anchor tags for "My Hobbies" and "Contact Me" got squished together and its above the table even though it comes after the table on lines 79 and 80. What needs fixing?

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>HTML</td>
          <td>★★★★★</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CSS</td>
          <td>★★</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Javascript</td>
        <td>★</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Node</td>
        <td>★</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <hr>
  <a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
```

Comment: Please post your css too

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please create a [mcve] that includes both your HTML and CSS. Consider using a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Also, you're missing a few closing tags, and `hr` and `a` elements can't be direct descendants of a `tr` element.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid... https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: `<a>` tags display inline (not block), and thus get "squished together" by default. What were you expecting?

Comment: @kmoser I wasn't sure what to expect seeing as how I mentioned I am an "absolute beginner" at the beginning of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just close your first table.  But why in the world do you need to insert a table in a table in this example?

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}

.top {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  
}

.bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.right {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

#fin td,
#fin tr {
  padding: 0;
}

#fin tr{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>HTML</td>
          <td>★★★★★</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CSS</td>
          <td>★★</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Javascript</td>
          <td>★</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Node</td>
          <td>★</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
</table>
<hr>
<a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>

<table border="1">
  <tr>

    <td>HTML</td>
    <td>★★★★★</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CSS</td>
    <td>★★</td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>Javascript</td>
    <td>★</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Node</td>
    <td>★</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<hr>
<a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>


<table id='fin'>
  <tr class='top'><!--
    --><td class='top left'>HTML</td><!--
    --><td class = 'top right'>★★★★★</td><!--
    --><td class='top left'>Javascript</td><!--
    --><td class='top right'>★</td><!--
  --></tr><!--
  --><tr class='bottom'><!--
    --><td class='bottom left'>CSS</td><!--
    --><td class = 'bottom right'>★★</td><!--
    --><td class='bottom left'>Node</td><!--
    --><td class='bottom right'>★</td><!--
  --></tr>

</table>
<hr>
<a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
```

Comment: It was an exercise in a Udemy course that required me to add the star emojis next to the text in the table. To be honest it felt counter intuitive and I felt like there had to be an easier or more sensible way of doing it. In any case thank you.